# FileReader for text file in Android

Tags: android, filereader, file-not-found

Good times!

My Android app is trying to read simple text file, using usual Java combination

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("file:///android_asset/example.txt");
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

But what ever I do, I'm getting File not Found exeption, although there is another html-file in this directory and shown in WebView correctly.
So, my question is:
FileReader can be used for simple reading text file or I have to use InputStream ?

Comment: why don't you use InputStream to read files from asset folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to InputStream like as follows.Change the code like this.I hope it will work:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file:///android_asset/example.txt");
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Comment: I am getting a sytax error for this.It is asking me to change the type of fr to InputStream

Comment: Same as @Nikhil, literally copy and pasting that code snippet into Eclipse gives that syntax error?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. `InputStreamReader` is the "reader of a stream". Hence when creating it, it is looking for some sort of `InputStream`. `FileReader` is definitely not this. In fact, the code he has in the question, seems to be exactly right, the `FileNotFoundException` he refers to would just be being generated from an incorrect filepath would be my guess (specifically - incorrect way of trying to read the assets folder). Also, I have run his exact code and used it for reading files, and it works perfectly. p.s. Yes, I am 99.9% sure my imports were correct

Comment: @BT yes you are 100% correct.Thanks for correcting me.Edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `getAssets()` method.

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("example.txt")));
```

Answer (score 6):

Android doesn't know ***where*** your files are located. You have to use ***their*** functions. See the section called [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), especially the section on [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and the methods in the [Android Context class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) for opening and writing to files. For example you could use the Context method [getFileStreamPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) to get a Java File object and pass that to a Java FileReader.

```
File yourFile = getFileStreamPath(YOUR_FILENAME);
if (yourFile.exists()) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourFile));
    ...
    in.close();
}
```

P.S. Here's a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5452545/1020470) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5453132/1020470).